# How to track number of domains which have been crawled in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) Spider which will crawl about 1000 domains. I am thinking if there is any way to track number of domains crawled. because it will take long time to crawl 1000 domains in one using process.

if I could track number of domains process then I can trigger some task like sending email after crawling of 100 domains out of 1000.

I tried to find on internet but could not get relevant.

if anyone know someway please tell me. if I would not find any way then I have to track number of urls crawled. but it would be good if number of domains can be tracked.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'alok2'
    # 'list.txt' file have domains which I have to crawl
    allowed_domains = [i.split('\n')[0] for i in open('list.txt','r').readlines()]
    start_urls = ['http://'+i.split('\n')[0] for i in open('list.txt','r').readlines()]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item',follow=True)]

    def __init__(self,category=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.count=0 #this is to keep track of domains whose all links have been crawled

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        self.parse_item(response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        #lines
        #lines
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "domain crawled": is it when you processed all links from that domain (that could be very very long), or when you encounter a new domain.
Anyhow, I suggest you look at [`OffsiteMiddleware`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/offsite.py) for inspiration.

When the spider is opened, this middleware creates a `set()`

```
def spider_opened(self, spider):
    self.domains_seen = set()
```

And for each spider callback output it checks Requests if the domain is allowed or not, depending on the spider's `allowed_domains` attribute, but in your case I'm guessing you have an empty `allowed_domains`.
You can change that to something like:

```
def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
    for x in result:
        if isinstance(x, Request):
            domain = urlparse_cached(x).hostname
            if domain and domain not in self.domains_seen:
                self.domains_seen.add(domain)
                if (len(self.domains_seen) % 100) == 0:
                    log.msg("seen %d domains so far" % len(self.domains_seen))
        yield x
```

Comment: 'domain crawled' means domain whose all the links has been crawled.

Comment: You'll probably need to look at the scheduler, periodically checking if some domain have no activity for some time

Comment: scrapy.signals.item_scraped(item, response, spider)   > https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html?highlight=Scheduler